Understanding Discrepancies Between Frequentist and Bayesian Parametric Weibull Models in Accelerated Failure Time Analysis
Currently in the process of identifying a Bayesian Weibull Survival AFT model that is equivalent to the survreg() Weibull AFT model results from the Survival package in R. I came across this publication and I am trying to match the survreg results with the use of low informative priors. I have not succeeded yet.
Are these two models equivalent (bayewei vs. freqwei)? If yes, why the results are different and how can I acquire comparable results?
 mc<- structure(list(V1 = c(5.3, 6.8, 5.7, 3.7, 6, 6.3, 7.9, 5.9, 7.6, 
                            7.1, 6, 6.9, 6.1, 8.8, 5.6, 6.1, 5, 6.6, 5.6, 6.1), 
                     V2 = structure(c(1L, 
                                      1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                      2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
                     V3 = c(0, 
                            0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), 
                     X = c(1.65, 
                           1.79, 1.77, 2.74, 4.62, -0.86, 2.7, 3.47, 1.95, 4.3, 2.52, 1.95, 
                           2.78, 2.7, 4.25, -0.19, 3.76, 0.68, 1.48, -0.06), 
                     Time = c(38.863, 
                              24.2, 120.373, 16.5, 115.533, 8.613, 106.997, 105.71, 105.963, 
                              35.42, 107.613, 14.113, 105.82, 14.377, 99.253, 34.793, 96.657, 
                              94.347, 91.19, 8.613), 
                     Status = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
                                1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)), 
                row.names = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 
                              5L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 20L, 21L, 24L, 25L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
                              37L, 40L, 41L, 42L), class = "data.frame")
    
    library(rjags)
    library(survival)


BayesSurv<-function(form="X", data=mc, model="weibull",
                    prior_mu=0, prior_prec=1,var,
                    eventvariable="Status",
                    timevariable="Time",
                    niter=10000, nthin=10,nburn=1000){
  .formula <- reformulate(form)
  data$event<-data[,eventvariable]
  data$time<-data[,timevariable]
  X <- model.matrix(object=.formula, data = data)

  time_un <- data$time[data$event==1]
  cen_un <- data$time[data$event==1]
  is.censored_un <- rep(0, length(cen_un))
  X_un <- X[data$event==1, ]

  cen_cen <- data$time[data$event==0]
  time_cen <- rep(NA, length(cen_cen))
  is.censored_cen <- rep(1, length(cen_cen))
  X_cen <- X[data$event==0, ]

  time <- c(time_un, time_cen)
  cen <- c(cen_un, cen_cen)
  is.censored <- c(is.censored_un, is.censored_cen)
  Xnew <- rbind(X_un, X_cen)
  
  cat("model{ 
for(i in 1:n){
is.censored[i]~dinterval(time[i],cen[i])
time[i]~dweib(alpha,lambda[i])
lambda[i]<-exp(-mu[i]*alpha)
mu[i]<-inprod(beta[],X[i,])}

#Prior distributions
for(l in 1:(Nbetas)){
beta[l]~dnorm(mu.betaMain[l],prec.betaMain[l])}
alpha ~ dunif(0, 10)
}",file = "AFT.txt")
  
  d.jags <- list(n = nrow(X), time = time, cen = cen, X = Xnew, is.censored = is.censored, Nbetas = ncol(X),mu.betaMain=prior_mu,prec.betaMain=prior_prec)
  i.jags <- function() list(beta = rnorm(ncol(X),sd = 1), alpha = runif(1,min = 0.1,max = 10))
  p.jags <- c("beta", "alpha")
  
  
  m1 <- rjags::jags.model(data = d.jags, file = "AFT.txt", inits = i.jags, n.chains = 1)
  
  # Burn-in and update
  update(m1, nburn)
  res <- coda.samples(m1, variable.names = p.jags, n.iter = niter, thin = nthin)
  results <- as.mcmc(do.call(rbind, res))
  
  return(results)
}


freqwei<-summary(survreg(Surv(Time,Status)~V1 + V2 + V3 + X, data=mc))


outn<-BayesSurv(form="V1 + V2 + V3 + X",prior_mu=c(0,rep(0,5)),prior_prec=c(rep(0.001,5)),
                           data = mc,niter = 20000)
bayewei=summary(outn)
bayewei


BOut<-cbind(freqwei$coefficients,
                bayewei[2]$quantiles[,3][-1])
BOut


After communication with the author of the manuscript, it was noted to me that the parametrization of this Bayesian AFT model accounts for the scale parameter. Thus, if the ratio of −β/γ (acceleration factor) is calculated the results of survreg() are comparable.
A quick way to change the parameters can be found also here
https://rdrr.io/cran/SurvRegCensCov/man/ConvertWeibull.html
